# Authorize to artifactory from desktop app

Tags: c#, authorization, artifactory

My program (C#/WPF) lets me export all users from artifactory. In development, I used a hard coded access token to authorize all API requests, which I cannot leave in the finished product for security reasons. As far as I know however, you need a token or key to use the API. Therefore, my question is if there is a way to use username and password to obtain an access token.

The Artifactory version in use is Enterprise Plus 7.55.10.

I tried opening the login page in an internal browser (CefSharp) and retrieving the access token from the cookies, which worked, but using it resulted in an "Unauthorized" error (I am admin though).

This kind of thing is not really my expertise. If you need any code or additional information, please let me know. Thanks